# facet grid of multiple barplots containing group means

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have a dataframe with variables Group (demented, nondemented), sex (M, F) and Age.Group ( (60,70], (70,80], (80,90], (90,100] ) and MMSE (a continuous numerical variable representing a "score" on an assessment). I want to create a bar graph with a bar for each group (demented versus non demented) and the group mean on the y-axis. I then want to create a facet grid so there are 8 separate bar charts, one for M and one for F in each age group. Can't figure out how to get a bar graph in ggplot to have a different variable on the y-axis. Would appreciate any tips!

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your data is a bit like this:

```r
set.seed(69)

age <- cut(sample(1:39, 500, TRUE) + 60, breaks = 10 * 6:10)
condition <- factor(sample(c("demented", "not demented"), 500, TRUE))
MMSE <- as.numeric(condition) * 10 + 10 - as.numeric(age) + 1 + rnorm(500)
MMSE <- round(MMSE)
MMSE[MMSE > 30] <- 30
sex <- sample(c("male", "female"), 500, TRUE)

df <- data.frame(age, condition, MMSE, sex)
```

Then you have various options to present your data. One is to have all sixteen bars in a single plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(age, sex, condition) %>% 
  summarize(MMSE = mean(MMSE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(condition, MMSE, fill = sex)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  facet_grid(~age, switch = "x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Or facet by sex and condition:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(age, sex, condition) %>% 
  summarize(MMSE = mean(MMSE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, MMSE, fill = sex)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  facet_grid(condition~sex) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or just by sex:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(age, sex, condition) %>% 
  summarize(MMSE = mean(MMSE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, MMSE, fill = condition)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  facet_grid(~sex) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or just by condition:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(age, sex, condition) %>% 
  summarize(MMSE = mean(MMSE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, MMSE, fill = sex)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  facet_grid(~condition) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]